# Requirement of 64-bit version DLLs in a .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

#### Introduction

I'm working on a .net project, in which I'm using some 32-bit version DLLs. The list of DLLs are:

1. System.*
2. Microsoft.*
3. AWSSDK.*
4. Npgsql.dll
5. Newtonsoft.Json.dll
6. Some other dlls from other vendors

(The list of DLLs is actually too long to be attached in this post without making it too long.)

#### Requirement

I require 64-bit version DLLs only and at the moment, I only have 32-bit version DLLs in our hand.

#### Things that I have tried

I verified the DLLs' version using a tool named SigCheck.

I tried to find/convert the DLL version using the following methods:

1. I searched on the internet and NuGet Package Manager but, I was not able to find 64-bit DLLs.
2. I tried recompiling the project to 64 bit by changing below setting under project properties:
   *- Build -> Platform Target -> x64*

After compilation, the project DLL got converted to 64-bit. However, the remaining project DLLs' version didn't change.

#### Question

I would be grateful if someone could share documentation links/steps to convert 32-bit version DLLs to a 64-bit version?

or

Could someone please send us a link to find recompiled 64-bit version of the given DLLs?

Please note that I'm using .NET framework 4.6

Comment: hrm... Just switch your app to x64 (or event better, any cpu) and update your nugets ?

Comment: Up vote this question please, I have a similar issue, i need x64 bit dlls for Web Application Firewall in IIS.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the comment. I tried doing the steps

Uninstalled Newtonsoft.json.dll.
Changed app to x64.
Cleaned the project.
Installed Newtonsoft.json.dll again from Nuget.

Finally, Checked both dll versions. 
Project.dll is 64-bit
Newtonsoft.json.dll is 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed .Net dlls are usually platform agnostic. So for most of the libraries you do not need to worry about it, just use nuget to refer to the libraries and you should be good to go. The JIT compiler will take care of compiling the assemblies to 64/32 bit depending on the platform.

The platform target you specify when compiling a dll only sets a flag in the dll. This flag can be changed with [CorFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool), but if it has a 32-bit flag it might be for a reason.

The big problem usually occurs when you need to use native assemblies (i.e. c++ dlls). These need to be platform specific. The best solution is to get 64-bit versions of these DLLs, but you would need to get them from the vendor of the libray and update the references in your projects. The most common workaround if you can not get a 64-bit version is to run the library in a separate 32-bit process.

Comment: I checked the CorFlags tool with some of the DLLs and saw that the 32bitreq flag was 0 for them. Does it mean that they are 64-bit dlls? Also, before reaching to vendors, is there any way that I can try to change the DLL version to 64-bit myself?

Comment: If the 32bit flags are not set then the library should be platform agnostic, i.e. "Any CPU". And this should be the case for the vast majority of libraries. Native libraries must be recompiled from source since they contain actual x86/x64 instructions rather than IL instructions.